# Parsing XML SOAP with Python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, soap, request

I need parse this XML with python, I can get the content, but I can't interpret it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance">  
  <soapenv:Body> 
    <ns1:executeResponse xmlns:ns1="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">  
      <executeReturn xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" soapenc:arrayType="ns1:NameValuePair[19]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">  
        <executeReturn href="#id0"/>  
        <executeReturn href="#id1"/>  
        <executeReturn href="#id2"/>  
        <executeReturn href="#id3"/>  
        <executeReturn href="#id4"/>  
        <executeReturn href="#id5"/>  
        <executeReturn href="#id6"/>  
        <executeReturn href="#id7"/>  
        <executeReturn href="#id8"/>  
        <executeReturn href="#id9"/>  
        <executeReturn href="#id10"/>  
        <executeReturn href="#id11"/>  
        <executeReturn href="#id12"/>  
        <executeReturn href="#id13"/>  
        <executeReturn href="#id14"/>  
        <executeReturn href="#id15"/>  
        <executeReturn href="#id16"/>  
        <executeReturn href="#id17"/>  
        <executeReturn href="#id18"/> 
      </executeReturn> 
    </ns1:executeResponse>  
    <multiRef xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" id="id7" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:NameValuePair">  
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">wagerSerialNumber</name>  
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">1174-726686778-20</value> 
    </multiRef>  
    <multiRef xmlns:ns3="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id3" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns3:NameValuePair">  
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">address</name>  
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">10.71.58.190</value> 
    </multiRef>  
    <multiRef xmlns:ns4="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id12" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns4:NameValuePair">  
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">resultText</name>  
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">ok</value> 
    </multiRef>  
    <multiRef xmlns:ns5="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id10" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns5:NameValuePair">  
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">stateId</name>  
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">01</value> 
    </multiRef>  
    <multiRef xmlns:ns6="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id13" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns6:NameValuePair">  
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">requestedBoardData</name>  
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">1,4,10,12,15,51</value> 
    </multiRef>  
    <multiRef xmlns:ns7="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id5" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns7:NameValuePair">  
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">time</name>  
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">06:24:25</value> 
    </multiRef>  
    <multiRef xmlns:ns8="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id18" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns8:NameValuePair">  
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">applicationRevision</name>  
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">1</value> 
    </multiRef>  
    <multiRef xmlns:ns9="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns9:NameValuePair">  
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">boletoReferenceNumber</name>  
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">70250000171153857</value> 
    </multiRef>  
    <multiRef xmlns:ns10="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id2" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns10:NameValuePair">  
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">sequenceNumber</name>  
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">1</value> 
    </multiRef>  
    <multiRef xmlns:ns11="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id8" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns11:NameValuePair">  
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">sessionID</name>  
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">70250000100</value> 
    </multiRef>  
    <multiRef xmlns:ns12="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id4" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns12:NameValuePair">  
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">checksum</name>  
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string" xsi:nil="true"/> 
    </multiRef>  
    <multiRef xmlns:ns13="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id1" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns13:NameValuePair">  
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">drawNumber</name>  
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">2379</value> 
    </multiRef>  
    <multiRef xmlns:ns14="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id16" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns14:NameValuePair">  
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">prodRevision</name>  
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">110</value> 
    </multiRef>  
    <multiRef xmlns:ns15="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id9" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns15:NameValuePair">  
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">foreignPosId</name>  
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">1</value> 
    </multiRef>  
    <multiRef xmlns:ns16="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id17" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns16:NameValuePair">  
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">drawDate</name>  
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">12/12/2010</value> 
    </multiRef>  
    <multiRef xmlns:ns17="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id14" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns17:NameValuePair">  
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">storeId</name>  
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">1</value> 
    </multiRef>  
    <multiRef xmlns:ns18="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id11" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns18:NameValuePair">  
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">transactionTime</name>  
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">12:27:26</value> 
    </multiRef>  
    <multiRef xmlns:ns19="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id15" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns19:NameValuePair">  
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">chainId</name>  
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">13</value> 
    </multiRef>  
    <multiRef xmlns:ns20="http://service.escb2b.gtech.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id6" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns20:NameValuePair">  
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string">totalWagerAmount</name>  
      <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">3000</value> 
    </multiRef> 
  </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I get name and value?
I already tried something similar to:

```
# define namespace mappings to use as shorthand below
namespaces = {
    'soap': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
    'a': 'http://www.etis.fskab.se/v1.0/ETISws',
}
dom = ElementTree.fromstring(response.content)

# reference the namespace mappings here by `<name>:`
names = dom.findall(
    './soap:Body'
    '/a:GetStartEndPointResponse'
    '/a:GetStartEndPointResult'
    '/a:StartPoints'
    '/a:Point'
    '/a:Name',
    namespaces,
)
print names
for name in names:
    print(name.text)
```

I need to get the data that is inside the multiRef tags, I was searching and reading but I don't understand the logic of reading this kind of files.
I have read other people recommending zeep to parse soap xml but I found it hard to get my head around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did.

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

data = """......""" # xml data here. 

namespaces = {
    'soap': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
    'a': 'http://www.etis.fskab.se/v1.0/ETISws',
}

tree = ET.parse(StringIO(data))
root = tree.getroot()

names = [x.text for x in root.findall('.//multiRef/name', namespaces)]
values = [x.text for x in root.findall('.//multiRef/value', namespaces)]

print(names)
print(values)
```

gives the output

```
['wagerSerialNumber', 'address', 'resultText', 'stateId', 'requestedBoardData', 'time', 'applicationRevision', 'boletoReferenceNumber', 'sequenceNumber', 'sessionID', 'checksum', 'drawNumber', 'prodRevision', 'foreignPosId', 'drawDate', 'storeId', 'transactionTime', 'chainId', 'totalWagerAmount']

['1174-726686778-20', '10.71.58.190', 'ok', '01', '1,4,10,12,15,51', '06:24:25', '1', '70250000171153857', '1', '70250000100', None, '2379', '110', '1', '12/12/2010', '1', '12:27:26', '13', '3000']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, but what is the value of the namespaces variable?

Comment: Same as what you have in your post.

Comment: Updated the answer